# ASP.NET Entity Framework Scaffolded edit - Read only fields for certain users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I currently have a bog standard scaffolded ASP.NET application with views/edits for data in an SQL back end.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UPSCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.UPSCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UPSCheck, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NASCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.NASCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NASCheck, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The page is also using Windows Authentication, and the username is available through

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

What I want to do is lock-down certain parts of the edit page to only allow certain users to change certain fields. I can't find anything on line that suggests and easy way to do this so I'm reaching out to the experts!

Any help or direction is much appreciated.

Comment: How are we supposed to know who is allowed or not?  Is there a specific AD group that some will be a member of?

Comment: Sorry should have put that in the initial post. In this instance it's one username, so essentially DOMAIN\USERNAME is what User.Identity.Name would resolve to in page.

Comment: Okay, that seems like a pretty simple `@if (User.Identity.Name == "x") {`, what am I missing?

Comment: I tried this initially, but the edit when viewed by a user who had it read only submitted a blank value back to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default authentication model in asp.net is `RBAC` - `Role Based Authentication Control`. That mean that you can check user role to allow/disallow some action. User is implementation of `IPrincipal` interface, that mean that you can use `bool IsInRole(string roleName)` method to check access rights in your view.

Here is more about `IPrincipal`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx

Example(this will show editor field only if the user is `admin`):

```
@if(User.IsInRole("admin")){
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.yourPropertyName)      
}else{
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.yourPropertyName)
}
```

Other way(this will show disabled field if the user is not admin):

```
@if(User.IsInRole("admin")){
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.yourPropertyName)
}else{
   // That will make field disabled
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.yourPropertyName, new {disabled= "disabled" })
}
```

Comment: This is promising but when I tried this with a bog standard if, when none admin users edit the page and submit it, it submits a blank entry for the fields that are not there and then overwrites the initial value

Comment: You can still use `@Html.HiddenFor(...)` html helper to prevent null values. Also don't forget to check fields on server-side, because user can emulate request.

Answer (score 0):

you can make something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UPSCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.UPSCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UPSCheck, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
@if(User.Identity.Name=="Domain\UserName")
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NASCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.NASCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NASCheck, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
}
else
{
   //you display the read only par
   //in addition add
   @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.NASCheck)
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I did try this but when a user who can't edit this submits ANY change to the entire model, it then submits a blank value to the database.

Comment: you can add @Html.HiddenFor in case of those they are not able to edit

Comment: @Trinitrotoluene i edited the answer for you, this will solve your problem